# How can others vote to undelete when nobody can find my question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

I have a deleted question that I have voted for undeletion. I need two more votes until it is undeleted. But how can anyone vote to undelete when nobody can find my question? If I log out, there comes a 'File not found (404)' page.

[image: deleted question]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[10-kers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can see deleted posts and undelete votes in their [10K-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today).

If you post a link to your question and expand a little bit on why it needs to be undeleted we can see if we agree.

Another option is to join a chat room that has some regulars to help out. A good starting point is the [The Meta room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room)