# Do posts with "undelete" votes go into any review queue?

Tags: support, vote-to-undelete

Related questions include [Should potentially useful self-deleted questions be undeleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285841) and its duplicate, [Should I undelete a question with answers that was deleted by the original OP?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314325)

I recently wrote an answer to a question, and shortly after posting the answer, the author of the question deleted his question, along with my answer.

Frankly, when I first read the question I felt surely it had already been answered before and was basic enough to warrant closure if not deletion. But I searched Stack Overflow and could not find anything that directly addressed the question. Furthermore, while the question was fairly basic in nature, I could not find anything about it that would make it off-topic. It was indeed a practical question about programming, and so I came to the conclusion that rather than a close vote, it deserved an answer. So I wrote one.

But now the question and my answer are deleted. I've contributed my own "undelete" vote to the question, but **is there any mechanism by which this question would automatically be presented to other Stack Overflow users**, such as the "undelete" vote placing the question into a review queue? As far as I know, the "Reopen" queue is only for closed-but-not-deleted posts.

If not, what other non-automatic mechanisms may I or should I use to solicit additional "undelete" votes? I try to shy away from advertising the post itself on Meta (doing so smells sometimes too much like raising a posse), but maybe that's a reasonable course of action here? Posting a message to the ["Close Vote Reviewers" chat room][3]? Handling "undelete" votes is not specifically mentioned in [the FAQ for that room][4], but the FAQ does describe the room's charter as "broadened", and "undelete" seems like it would fit in with the other activities listed (such as "reopen" voting).

**Addendum:**

Now that my question is live, the site is showing another "Related" link that seems pertinent to me (and elaborates a little on the comment about moderator tools below): [Vote to undelete when nobody can find my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296936/vote-to-undelete-when-nobody-can-find-my-question?rq=1)

Comment: In the moderation tools, there's a section on recently cast delete / undelete votes. There's not w review queue as such though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When a post gets a delete vote or undelete vote on it it enters the [10k tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) delete tab.  10k+ reputation users can go through there to see what should be deleted or undeleted. (Note: one can navigate to this tab by clicking the "reviews" link at the top of the Stack Overflow page, and then clicking the "Tools" link to the left of the "Review" link near the top of that page.)

Other than that you can always come into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and ask for an [undelete-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undelete-pls) request.  We may or may not act on it (as users individually judge each request), but it will get the post in front of more eyeballs.

I have also updated our [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) to explicitly call out that we allow undelete request.

Comment: Thanks...I've visited the "reviews" link hundreds of times, and never even noticed the "Tools" tab. I had no idea it existed. :/ Thanks to your answer, now I do (but I'm guessing the chat room is a better place to solicit for undelete votes).